# not work with JQuery in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, checkbox

I have a CheckBox

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" Text="Type of Change"></asp:CheckBox>
```

and a funcion, that work correctly, however only the alert appears "Work" but the checkbox not It updates

```
function Checks() {
    var value1 = "false"

    if (value1 == "false") {
        alert("Work");
        $("#CheckBox2").prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        alert("False");
    }
}
```

When loading the page you can see the checkbox checked without any problem

```
$("#CheckBox2").prop('checked', true);

    function Checks() {
        var value1 = "false"

        if (value1 == "false") {
            alert("Work");
        } else {
            alert("False");
        }
    }
```

I think the checkbox should be updated somehow when entering the if

Comment: `$("CheckBox2")` is saying `<CheckBox2 />` element

Comment: @epascarello How should it be?, How do you work out of the function?

Comment: jQuery selectors.... learn about them.... You are using an element selector, not an id selector. https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: @epascarello Sorry, I forgot the #, but not work

Comment: Been a long time since I worked with C# but don;t they change the ids of serverside elements.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate epascarello's comment above, client id of asp.net server controls is different from server side id.
In order to make above code work use it like this :

```
var checkBoxID = "<%= CheckBox2.ClientID %>" ;  
$("#" + checkBoxID ).prop('checked', true);
```

Also suggest you to read this excellent post by Rick Strahl on [A generic way to find ASP.NET ClientIDs with jQuery](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2009/Oct/15/A-generic-way-to-find-ASPNET-ClientIDs-with-jquery)

Hope this helps !